# how to code format string for 40 digits with negative and positive sign in c#?

Tags: c#, biginteger

how can I use format string to define custom constructor for initialize one huge integer with 40 digits.
so, I must store this variable in string. However, I do not know how to define these constrain.
how to check this string has less than 40 digits? and it includes just numbers, negative sing, and positive sing???

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: you can use BigInteger

Comment: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: BTW, 40 digits is about 137 bits. BigInteger can accommodate this for sure.

Comment: _BigInteger Represents an __arbitrarily large__ signed integer._

Answer (score 1):

You can check for each character for a string using `char.IsDigit` method if its a number and for the sign, you can check the first character if its `-` and for the length, you can check with the Length property.

Though I would suggest you use [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1). It's 16 byte and can store 40 digits

Comment: _BigInteger Represents an __arbitrarily large__ signed integer._

Answer (score 1):

While @vivek nuna's answer is correct, I wanted to give an alternative solution. You can do this using RegEx, which is my preferred solution. For example: `"-?\d+"` would check if the string contains numbers only, and it can (but doesn't have to) contain a `-` at the start of the string.

Also, when using big numbers, consider using [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netcore-3.1) instead of string.

Answer (score 0):

Although I completely disagree with using a string to store a number, and doing string math, I can offer the solution of using a structure to store the sign and the digits separately

Below is an example implementation with *some* bells and whistles to make it workable with other types. It lacks the core algebra functions needed here.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StrInteger a = new StrInteger("927365491278374955737294854895695540");
        StrInteger b = new StrInteger("-927365491278374955737294854895695540");

        if (a == -b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check");
        }
    }
}
```

and the implementation of `StrInteger`.

```
public struct StrInteger : IEquatable<StrInteger>
{
    #region Factory
    public StrInteger(int number) : this(Math.Sign(number), Math.Abs(number).ToString()) { }
    public StrInteger(long number) : this(Math.Sign(number), Math.Abs(number).ToString()) { }
    public StrInteger(uint number) : this(1, number.ToString()) { }
    public StrInteger(ulong number) : this(1, number.ToString()) { }
    public StrInteger(string description) : this()
    {
        this = Parse(description);
    }
    public StrInteger(int sign, string digits) : this()
    {
        Digits=digits??throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(digits));
        Sign=sign;
    }
    public static implicit operator StrInteger(int number) => new StrInteger(number);
    public static implicit operator StrInteger(long number) => new StrInteger(number);
    public static implicit operator StrInteger(uint number) => new StrInteger(number);
    public static implicit operator StrInteger(ulong number) => new StrInteger(number);
    public static readonly StrInteger Zero = new StrInteger(0, "0");
    public static readonly StrInteger One = new StrInteger(1, "1");
    public static readonly StrInteger MinusOne = new StrInteger(-1, "1");

    public static StrInteger Parse(string description)
    {
        int sign = 1;
        description = description.Trim();
        if (description[0] == '-')
        {
            sign = -1;
            description = description.Substring(1);
        }
        if (description.Equals("0"))
        {
            sign = 0;
        }
        return new StrInteger(sign, description);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string Digits { get; }
    public int Sign { get; }
    public bool IsZero => Sign==0;
    #endregion

    #region IEquatable Members
    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(StrInteger)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is StrInteger item)
        {
            return Equals(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="StrInteger"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(StrInteger other)
    {
        // TODO: Implement equality check here
        return Digits.Equals(other.Digits)
            && Sign.Equals(other.Sign);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="StrInteger"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = -1817952719;
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + Digits.GetHashCode();
            hc = (-1521134295)*hc + Sign.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }
    public static bool operator ==(StrInteger target, StrInteger other) { return target.Equals(other); }
    public static bool operator !=(StrInteger target, StrInteger other) { return !target.Equals(other); }
    #endregion

    #region Formatting
    public override string ToString()
    {
        switch (Sign)
        {
            case 0:
                return "0";
            case 1:
                return Digits;
            case -1:
                return "-" + Digits;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Algebra

    public StrInteger Add(StrInteger other)
    {
        // TODO: Implement addition
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public StrInteger Multiply(StrInteger other)
    {
        // TODO: Implement multiplication
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public StrInteger Negate() => new StrInteger(-Sign, Digits);

    public static StrInteger operator +(StrInteger a) => a;
    public static StrInteger operator -(StrInteger a) => a.Negate();
    public static StrInteger operator +(StrInteger a, StrInteger b) => a.Add(b);
    public static StrInteger operator -(StrInteger a, StrInteger b) => a.Add(b.Negate());
    public static StrInteger operator *(StrInteger a, StrInteger b) => a.Multiply(b);
    #endregion
}
```